# Receiving a file over a network loses some packets when receiving

Tags: c++, winsock2

I have made a server and client program in c++. I used winsock2.h for this project. I made the program be able to send and receive files over the network. The server program and client program are two separate projects because making the program in the same project is not possible to check them.

When i run both client and server in a single device and try sending a text from the client to the server and vice versa, it succeeds, even sending files from server to client and vice versa also works.

When i run server in a device and client on another, sending text succeeds (probably because its just a single packet). Sending files however tends to have some faults. i have the packet size set to 1024 bytes, and whenever sending a single packet, it works. but when i try sending more than couple packets, it fails to receive couple packets at the last. i tried with files of multiple sizes and it failed multiple times at the last couple packets. i thought the problem was with my stack-based code and so i tried changing it to heap, and it .. still didnt work . it's been a while since i couldnt figure out the problem. I tried checking out places that might have the similar problems, but i wasnt able to find a solution to it.

These are my codes :

**Receive function in Server program**

```
bool Server::ReceiveFile()
{
    if (!is_still_connected(clientSocket)) { PRINT("Client has disconnected"); return false; }


    if (!is_ConnectedWithAClient)return false;

    //Receive File name to use 
    if (!ReceiveText()) {
        PRINT_ERR("Failed to receive file name!!");
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "Received file name: " << text << std::endl;
    std::string filename = text;

    std::string filepath = File_Path + filename;

    // Receive the file size
    if (!ReceiveText())
    {
        PRINT_ERR("Failed to receive file size!!");
    }
    PRINT_LOG("Received File size: " + text + " bytes.");

    int fileSize = std::stoi(text);

    if (!CreateFilepath(filepath))return false;

    std::ofstream file(filepath, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file) {
        PRINT_ERR("Failed to create file: " + filename);
        return false;
    }
    PRINT_LOG("File created successfully at path: " + filepath);

    //char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char* buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int totalBytesReceived = 0;
    int emptycounter = 0;
    while (totalBytesReceived < fileSize)
    {
        bytesRecv = recv(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, 0);
        if (bytesRecv == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            PRINT_ERR("Failed to receive file data");
            return false;
        }

        totalBytesReceived += bytesRecv;

        if (bytesRecv < 1)  emptycounter++;
        else file.write(buffer, bytesRecv);

        if (emptycounter > 5)
        {
            if (totalBytesReceived < 1)PRINT_LOG("The file is empty!!");
            break;
        }

        PRINT_LOG("Bytes received for file: " + filename + " : " + std::to_string(bytesRecv));
        // Send acknowledgement message
        if (!SendText("ACK")) {
            PRINT_ERR("Failed to send acknowledgement message");
            delete[]buffer;
            return false;
        }

        // Wait for acknowledgement response from client
        if (!ReceiveText()) {
            PRINT_ERR("Failed to receive acknowledgement response");
            delete[]buffer;
            return false;
        }

        // Check if acknowledgement response is valid
        if (text != "ACK") {
            PRINT_ERR("Invalid acknowledgement response");
            delete[]buffer;
            return false;
        }
        Sleep(Sleep_timer);
        PRINT_LOG("Total Bytes received : " + filename + " : " + std::to_string(totalBytesReceived));
    }
    file.close();
    return true;
}
```

**Send function in client program**

```
bool Client::SendFile(std::string filepath)
{
    if (!is_ConnectedWiththeServer)return false;

    // Open the file
    std::ifstream file(filepath, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file) {
        PRINT_ERR("Failed to open file: " + filepath);
        return false;
    }

    // Extract the file name from the file path
    size_t fileNameStart = filepath.find_last_of("\\/") + 1;
    std::string fileName = filepath.substr(fileNameStart);

    // Get file size
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int fileSize = static_cast<int>(file.tellg());
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // Send file name 
    PRINT_LOG("Sending file: " + fileName);
    if (!SendText(fileName))
    {
        file.close();
        return false;
    }
    PRINT_LOG("Sent file name: " + fileName);

    // Send file size 
    PRINT_LOG("Sending file size: " + std::to_string(fileSize) + " bytes");

    std::string f_size = std::to_string(fileSize);
    if (!SendText(f_size))
    {
        file.close();
        return false;
    }
    PRINT_LOG("Sent file size: " + std::to_string(fileSize) + " bytes");


    // Send file contents
    //char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char* buffer=new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int totalBytesSent = 0;


    while (file)
    {
        file.read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE-1);
        int bytesRead = static_cast<int>(file.gcount());
        bytesSent = send(clientSocket, buffer, bytesRead, 0);
        if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            PRINT_ERR("Failed to send text");
            file.close();
            return false;
        }
        totalBytesSent += bytesSent;
        PRINT_LOG("Sent " + std::to_string(bytesSent) + " bytes from file");

        // Wait for acknowledgement message from server
        if (!ReceiveText()) {
            PRINT_ERR("Failed to receive acknowledgement message");
            delete[]buffer;
            return false;
        }

        // Send acknowledgement response to server
        if (!SendText("ACK")) {
            PRINT_ERR("Failed to send acknowledgement response");
            delete[]buffer;
            return false;
        }
        Sleep(Sleep_timer);
    }

    file.close();
    PRINT_LOG("Sent file data: " + std::to_string(totalBytesSent) + " bytes");

    return true;
}
```

**EDIT** These are the send and receive text, if thats necessary:

```
bool Server::ReceiveText()
{
    if (!is_still_connected(clientSocket)) { PRINT("Client has disconnected"); return false; }


    text = "";
    if (!CheckSocInit()) return false;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    bytesRecv = recv(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, 0);
    if (bytesRecv < 1) {
        PRINT_ERR("Failed to receive text");
        return false;
    }
    buffer[bytesRecv] = '\0';
    text += buffer;

    return true;
}
```

```
bool Server::SendText(std::string text)
{
    if (!is_still_connected(clientSocket)) { PRINT("Client has disconnected"); return false; }


    if (!is_ConnectedWithAClient)return false;
    bytesSent = send(clientSocket, text.c_str(), int(text.size()) + 1, 0);
    if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        PRINT_ERR("Failed to send text");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

They are almost same in both client and server. there are only some flag checks as the difference in both

BTW there are some macros i've been using for simplifying my understanding of the code. Here are the macros i've used in those code:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10240

#define PRINT_ERR(x) std::cerr<<"ERROR: "<<x<<std::endl;
#define PRINT_LOG(x) std::clog<<"LOG: "<<x<<std::endl;
#define PRINT(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
```

if possible, please point out the blunder mistakes i've done in the code that might or might not affect this question.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: We probably need to see how you're opening the socket (e.g,. if you're using UDP, packet loss and/or reordering is expected) as well as how you're doing framing for `SetText` and ``ReadText`.

Comment: You seem to assume that, for every `send` call sending `X` bytes, a `recv` call on the other end would receive exactly `X` bytes; and so therefore there would be a 1:1 correspondence between `send` and `recv` calls. This is not the case. Multiple `send` calls could be coalesced into one packet, or large `send` could be split into multiple packets, or in general a sequence of bytes passed to the OS via several `send` calls could be split into packets arbitrarily and received via more or fewer `recv` calls. Whereupon your `ACK`s won't line up.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: What you describe is correct for TCP. UDP has different problems to deal with.

Comment: im using TCP and not udp.

Comment: It's worth noting that TCP sends its own ACKs at the protocol layer, so it's not typically necessary to implement your own application-level ACK messages.  For file transfer, simply calling `recv()` until you have received all of the bytes is sufficient.  (The only potential issue is how to know when you've received all the bytes; you could deal with that by having the sender send a byte-count first, or for a cheap-and-simple solution, just assume that you've received all the bytes when `recv()` returns 0 to indicate that the sender has closed the TCP connection)

Comment: the 'ACK' part is just a check if the send and receive are working and is completely optional, that i know. but my question was, whenever i send a file from one device to another, for some reasons, the last couple packets doesnt get receive and the ```recv``` function just waits for the bytes to be received when the sender has already sent all the data from its end.

Comment: You send file data and your text commands all in the same stream, with no attempt to separating one from the other. Again, you seem to assume that, when `SendText` sends three bytes `ACK`, the corresponding `ReceiveText` would receive the exact same three bytes. In reality, it may receive fewer, or more; e.g. it may receive some bytes of the text followed by some bytes of the file contents. You then happily drop the latter on the floor, and never write them to the actual file.

Comment: I removed the ```ACK``` and it still doesnt work. 
i've tried the code in the localhost vs another device in the same network, when i use both in localhost, there is no problem in sending the file, whereas when sending the file over another device, i just cant seem to receive the last few packets when the file sending has more than couple packets like 5 or more.

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha: This is actually pretty common. On `localhost`, what you send as a single packet will typically be received as a single packet. When you send over a real network, that's a lot less likely to happen.

Comment: That is the problem.. if i had problems on localhost, i would've thought the problem was not the receive and send function, but the problem is in the network transfer and since i've not learned about other options to check these, my only option was to ask here. BTW im new to socket programming.. i still cant figure out the problem

Answer (score 1):

TCP works with a *stream* of data, so what you send with one call to `write` may or may not be read with a single call to `read`. When you're dealing with `localhost`, they typically will correspond--but when the data goes over a "real" network, they usually won't.

For example, let's say I'm trying send a file named `text.txt`, that contains "This is some text". The way you're sending things now, this will arrive on the receiving end, looking like this:

```cpp
text.txtThis is some text
```

There's nothing there to tell the receiver where the name of the file ends, and the content of the file begins. Right now, you're depending on what you send in one call to `write` being read with one call to `read`. But that's not always what will happen. For example, as short as the data above is, it's entirely possible you'd receive *all* the data (file name and file body) in your first call to `read.

To deal with that, you have to write your code so it doesn't depend on the two corresponding. You usually do that by writing something into the data you send to explicitly tell the receiver where one thing ends, and another begins.

For one possibility, when you're sending the file name, you could prefix it with the length of the filename, so on the receiving end, you'd read the length field, then use that to read the file name--without reading any of the content of the file as if it were part of the file name.

```cpp
bool sendFile(std::string_view fileName, socket dest) {
    uint32_t len = htonl(fileName.length());

    write(dest, (char *)&len, sizeof(len)); // write file name length
    write(dest, filename.c_str(), len);     // write file name itself

    // repeat essentially the same thing for the body of the file.
    // write the length of the file, followed by the content of the file
}
```

Then in the receiving end, you basically mirror that:

```cpp
uint32_t len;

read(src, (char *)&len, sizeof(len)); // read filename length
len = ntohl(len);
read(src, buffer, len);                // read filename itself

// then read a length for the body, then the body itself
```

Note: to support files over 4 gigabytes, you may want to expand the field for the length of the body to 8 bytes instead of 4.

This is over-simplifying though.

- On the read end, you typically want to allocate a buffer of reasonable, fixed size to read into, not attempt to read the whole file at once.
- A single read or write may not send/receive the whole amount you've
  asked for, so you typically have to write  little loop:

```cpp
while (bytes_to_send > 0) {
    auto bytes_sent = write(dest, buffer, len);
    if (bytes_sent > 0) 
        bytes_to_send -= bytes_sent;
    else {
       // writing failed--sort out what happened
    }
}
```

[...and similarly for reading.]

Depending on the situation, you may also want to consider adding a little ID to the beginning of each of those pieces (file name and file body). (e.g., "FN" for file name, and "BD" for the body). This makes it a lot easier to extend the format in the future, in you decided to transmit something else as well (e.g., file permissions).

Comment: I didnt get this one.. Basically what youre saying is i prefix everything except the file? I dont know how it will help me though

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha: I've edited to (I hope) clarify the situation.

Comment: i got what you're trying to say. i tried checking those before, and put as many logs as i could(like printing everything i receive over the network). i basically didnt find any problems before the file reading . if you're trying to say that the file data is sent before the file is actually read, then it might be true. but i actually have put delays to check that(which is not in the code i gave. i recently checked it), and it would (probably) reduce the problem that you said.